# Loop three times over a calendar

Tags: python-3.x, loops, datetime

I work for an emergency medical services agency and our ambulances run on shifts.
Shift A starts at 07:00 on January 1st and runs up until 07:00 on January 2nd
Shift B starts at 07:00 on January 2nd and stops at 07:00 on January 3rd.
Shift C starts at 07:00 on January 3rd and stops promptly at 07:00 on January 4th.

the pattern then starts over again with Shift A running for 24 hours, Shift B running for 24 hours, Shift C running for 24 hours and repeat the pattern.

Using Python 3.7, how do you program a loop to run three times for A, B and C ?
It needs to be run over a 24 hour schedule because I am doing further statistical analysis on the data. Such as How many emergencies happen on shift A versus shift B.
This is what I currently have:

```
#Who:   David
#What:  Generate a text file showing a calendar date with 24 hours with the shift of A, B or C
#When:  02 September 2020
#Where: Python 3.7
#Why:   The goal is to analyze shift patterns

import datetime

with open("c:\\temp\\calendar_shifts.txt", "w") as calendar_dates:
    calendar_dates.write("Key, Calendar, Shift" + "\n")
    date = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 6, 0, 0)
    shift = 'A'
    i = 0
    while (date < datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 7, 0, 0)):
        date += datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
        i = i + 1
        calendar_dates.write(str(i) + ', ' + str(date)+ ", " + str(shift) + "\n")
```

The end result look like:

```
Key, Calendar, Shift
1, 2020-01-01 07:00:00, A 
2, 2020-01-01 08:00:00, A 
3, 2020-01-01 09:00:00, A 
4, 2020-01-01 10:00:00, A 
5, 2020-01-01 11:00:00, A 
6, 2020-01-01 12:00:00, A 
7, 2020-01-01 13:00:00, A 
8, 2020-01-01 14:00:00, A 
9, 2020-01-01 15:00:00, A 
10, 2020-01-01 16:00:00, A 
11, 2020-01-01 17:00:00, A 
12, 2020-01-01 18:00:00, A 
13, 2020-01-01 19:00:00, A 
14, 2020-01-01 20:00:00, A 
15, 2020-01-01 21:00:00, A 
16, 2020-01-01 22:00:00, A 
17, 2020-01-01 23:00:00, A 
18, 2020-01-02 00:00:00, A 
19, 2020-01-02 01:00:00, A 
20, 2020-01-02 02:00:00, A 
21, 2020-01-02 03:00:00, A 
22, 2020-01-02 04:00:00, A 
23, 2020-01-02 05:00:00, A 
24, 2020-01-02 06:00:00, A 
25, 2020-01-02 07:00:00, B 
26, 2020-01-02 08:00:00, B 
27, 2020-01-02 09:00:00, B 
28, 2020-01-02 10:00:00, B 
29, 2020-01-02 11:00:00, B 
30, 2020-01-02 12:00:00, B 
31, 2020-01-02 13:00:00, B 
32, 2020-01-02 14:00:00, B 
33, 2020-01-02 15:00:00, B 
34, 2020-01-02 16:00:00, B 
35, 2020-01-02 17:00:00, B 
36, 2020-01-02 18:00:00, B 
37, 2020-01-02 19:00:00, B 
38, 2020-01-02 20:00:00, B 
39, 2020-01-02 21:00:00, B 
40, 2020-01-02 22:00:00, B 
41, 2020-01-02 23:00:00, B 
42, 2020-01-03 00:00:00, B 
43, 2020-01-03 01:00:00, B 
44, 2020-01-03 02:00:00, B 
45, 2020-01-03 03:00:00, B 
46, 2020-01-03 04:00:00, B 
47, 2020-01-03 05:00:00, B 
48, 2020-01-03 06:00:00, B 
49, 2020-01-03 07:00:00, C 
50, 2020-01-03 08:00:00, C 
51, 2020-01-03 09:00:00, C 
52, 2020-01-03 10:00:00, C 
53, 2020-01-03 11:00:00, C 
54, 2020-01-03 12:00:00, C 
55, 2020-01-03 13:00:00, C 
56, 2020-01-03 14:00:00, C 
57, 2020-01-03 15:00:00, C 
58, 2020-01-03 16:00:00, C 
59, 2020-01-03 17:00:00, C 
60, 2020-01-03 18:00:00, C 
61, 2020-01-03 19:00:00, C 
62, 2020-01-03 20:00:00, C 
63, 2020-01-03 21:00:00, C 
64, 2020-01-03 22:00:00, C 
65, 2020-01-03 23:00:00, C 
66, 2020-01-04 00:00:00, C 
67, 2020-01-04 01:00:00, C 
68, 2020-01-04 02:00:00, C 
69, 2020-01-04 03:00:00, C 
70, 2020-01-04 04:00:00, C 
71, 2020-01-04 05:00:00, C 
72, 2020-01-04 06:00:00, C 
73, 2020-01-04 07:00:00, A 
74, 2020-01-04 08:00:00, A 
75, 2020-01-04 09:00:00, A 
76, 2020-01-04 10:00:00, A 
etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to make an array of shift names, and every 24 hours change the shift to the next entry in the array, using modulo arithmetic to keep the array index in range:

```
import datetime

print("Key, Calendar, Shift" + "\n")
date = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 6, 0, 0)
shifts = ['A', 'B', 'C']
num_shifts = len(shifts)
shift = -1   # so that the first increment takes us to the first shift
i = 0
while (date < datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 7, 0, 0)):
    date += datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
    if i % 24 == 0:
        shift = (shift + 1) % num_shifts
    i = i + 1
    print(str(i) + ', ' + str(date)+ ", " + str(shifts[shift]) + "\n")
```

Output:

```
Key, Calendar, Shift
1, 2020-01-01 07:00:00, A
2, 2020-01-01 08:00:00, A
3, 2020-01-01 09:00:00, A
4, 2020-01-01 10:00:00, A
...
23, 2020-01-02 05:00:00, A
24, 2020-01-02 06:00:00, A
25, 2020-01-02 07:00:00, B
26, 2020-01-02 08:00:00, B
...
48, 2020-01-03 06:00:00, B
49, 2020-01-03 07:00:00, C
...
71, 2020-01-04 05:00:00, C
72, 2020-01-04 06:00:00, C
73, 2020-01-04 07:00:00, A
74, 2020-01-04 08:00:00, A
```

Comment: Thank you Nick: This does solve the problem. I never would have thought of using an array. Indeed what I cam up with still doesn't quite work. I cannot figure out how to make the loop happen more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nick. This helps tremendously. Also to note, I tried the following but could not get it to loop more than once.

```
with open("c:\\temp\\x.txt", "w") as calendar_dates:
    calendar_dates.write("Key, Calendar, Shift" + "\n")
    date = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 6, 0, 0)

    x = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    while (date < datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 7, 0, 0)):
        while (i < 24):
            shift = 'A'
            i = i + 1
            date += datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
            x = x + 1
            calendar_dates.write(str(x) + ', ' + str(date)+ ", " + str(shift) + "\n")
        while (j < 24):
            shift = 'B'
            j = j + 1
            date += datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
            x = x + 1
            calendar_dates.write(str(x) + ', ' + str(date)+ ", " + str(shift) + "\n")
        while (k < 24):
            shift = 'C'
            k = k + 1
            date += datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
            x = x + 1
            calendar_dates.write(str(x) + ', ' + str(date)+ ", " + str(shift) + "\n")
```

Comment: You can make this work by moving the initialisations `i = j = k = 0` to the first line in the outer `while` loop.